# How to patch C# binary?

Tags: patching, c#, dnspy

I have C# binary. I was able to use `dnSpy` to decompile it, and analyze. The binary was obfuscated with `xenocode` obfuscator.

I figured out that I can directly manipulate IL instructions if I just find correct instruction offset, and replace instruction byte(s).

Original bytes and C# code (replaced with letters so it is readable):

```
a.b().c.d = (int)e.f;

 06 6F A0010006 6F 9302000A
 ^  ^  ^        ^  ^-------- T2
 |  |  |        \----------- callvirt to set_d
 |  |  \-------------------- T1
 |  \----------------------- callvirt to get_f
 \-------------------------- ldloc.0
```

What I want to achieve and resulting bytes:

```
a.b().c.d = 6;

 1C 00 00000000 6F 9302000A
 ^  ^           ^  ^-------- T2
 |  |           \----------- callvirt to set_d
 |  |  
 |  \----------------------- 5x nop, so the length of file is same
 \-------------------------- ldc.i4.6
```

I am able to decompile changed binary without error, and I can observe my changed instructions, but when binary executes this region, it dies. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it really crash on that part of the program or maybe there's some check before that verifies if the binary hasn't been modified?

Comment: Hmm. It appears there's some external check.

Comment: So what is the actual error that you are getting? Can you share the binary?